# Ctrl+Z not working in Krita

Tags: krita

So, I'm currently using Krita to draw, however <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is not working. The button on the screen works fine, but the hotkey doesn't.

I tried a bit of research, but the only fix I found was using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, which didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE, this is more of a technical question to ask support about.  Not really something we can answer here.

Comment: Did you save and close the document, then reopen?  Ctrl+Z only works on edits you made while the image is open. Have you checked the list of shortcuts in the software?  Please add more information to your answer as it's difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore Settings > Configure Krita > Keyboard Shortcuts

[image]

It's not especially difficult to lose existing settings accidentally. In addition Krita is developed by volunteers. It can have and has bugs which get fixed slowly.

Comment: So you mean Krita developers are slower than Adobe in fixing problem areas? ;)

Comment: No. I said that bugs get fixed. It can happen slowly. About Adobe: It's well possible that Adobe doesn't even try.

Comment: In my experience opensource is quite good at killing bugs, especially critical ones. They just arent very good at consitency or very big investments. Whereas companies are good at investments but not so good at maintenance

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a non-English keyboard. For example, the German keyboard layout has swapped <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> keys.

Try writing something in a text editor to check it out.